# Distribution [into]? groups

Tags: prepositions

Suppose I sorted something, for example fruits, into groups, say apples, bananas, oranges.

Is it correct to say "the distribution of the fruits into the groups shows that the group of fruits consists of significantly more apples than oranges"?

I'm unsure about the "into". It feels like it might be something like "distribution onto groups" instead. However that feels wrong, too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks, across is the word I was looking for. The sentence I'm writing does refer specifically to the result of the classification as a distribution across the groups. If you copy those comments into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A native speaker would be much more likely to say *I **classified** the fruits into groups* rather than *I **distributed** the fruits into groups*. Hence he would also be more likely to say *The **classification** of the fruits into the groups shows that the group of fruits consists of significantly more apples than oranges* (alluding to the prior act of classifying / distributing).

Alternatively, *The **distribution** of the fruits **across** the groups* more explicitly references ***distribution*** as *the relative difference in numbers,* rather than the act of classifying itself.

That's to say, *the distribution **across** [some range of categories]* is the normal preposition usage when you want to focus on the fact that different categories have different (***types*** or ***numbers*** of) ***members***.